# Void menu, only some links scroll

Tags: navigation

I have been using void menu and adding the smoothScroll class to the menu links but they only work up until any , any void higher the `class="smoothScroll"` doesn't get printed.

I am not sure how the first four are getting the .smoothScroll added to them either as i set that up a while ago and can't figure it out how or where.